# how to set ng-src to conditionally search for IMG SRC?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a variable that contains the name of an image, so I set the source to be the path + variable + PNG. The thing is that at the beginning my var is null, so the SRC is not found and I get an error. How can I make the IMG to search for its source only when my variable is not null?

```
<img ng-src="images/{{server.purpose}}.png">
```

Where server.purpose contains the name of the picture according to a user selection. I get an error at the beginning because server.purpose is null. I want to use a condition that the img will look up for src only if server.purpose is not null. I tried with ng-if, but it just hide the img if not found, the error still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the value `null` for `ng-src` the call to the server is prevented. Therefore remove the hardcoded bits from `ng-src` and set it in the scope variable. Once the image needs to be shown put the whole path in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<div ng-if="variable">
  <img ng-src="..."/>
</div>
```